# Why the class can use undefined members in JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, el

I am reading JSP tutorial from a book and meeting a program that is hard to understand.

It has two beans, one is Message.java, another is MessageServies.java as below.

```
package com.jeecourse.model;

public class Message {
private String name;
private String text;
public Message() {
}
public Message(String name, String text) {
    this.name = name;
    this.text = text;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getText() {
    return text;
}
public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
}
```

And the MessageService.java

```
package com.jeecourse.model;

public class MessageService {
private Message[] fakeMessages;

public MessageService() {
    fakeMessages = new Message[3];
    fakeMessages[0] = new Message("Jimmy", "Jimmy's message!");
    fakeMessages[1] = new Message("Jack", "Jack's message!");
    fakeMessages[2] = new Message("Tom", "Tom's message!");
}

public Message[] getMessages() {
    return fakeMessages;
}
```

}

And finnally the message.jsp with EL:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:useBean id="messageService" class="com.jeecourse.model.MessageService"/>
<html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
                content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>NoteBook</title>
    </head>
  <body>
    <table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td><td>Message</td>
        </tr>
        <c: forEach var="message" items="${messageService.messages}">
            <tr>
                <td>${message.name}</td><td>${message.text}</td>
            </tr>
        </c: forEach>
    </table>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Please note here it uses messageService.messages in EL expression. It is very strange that messageService have neither such members, nor such functions. But it can work. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `${messageService.messages}` it gets translated at compile time to `messageService.getMessages`. Just in the same way that `${message.text}` is invoking actually `message.getText()`.

For this kind of "magic" it is important to follow some conventions when naming your methods. If not, the compiler won't know which method it should call when you use the abbreviated version.

You can see more about EL here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info
This feature is at the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! So that is to say, EL is able to covert the property to method.

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer to provide a link to more documentation